# What does . do in the command git add

Tags: git

I got a folder that I'm commiting to a repository using `git add .` but I do not know why it's necessary to use a . here I tried searching but couldn't find it.

Comment: it uses the current path imho

Comment: does not adding . use a different path if so which? thx for the answer <3

Comment: the dot is a synonymous of the current path and all below, meaning if your on /path and only want to add everything inside the folder you would use .since your comments are to short to interpret correctly please add more context